# Typescript not recognizing constructor of an un-typed node module

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-modules

This is my first time writing in TypeScript and JavaScript.I am now facing a problem where I need to work with a pretty old [Node Module](https://github.com/Brightspace/valence-sdk-javascript). I imported it like this:

```
import * as D2L from 'valence/lib/valence'
```

When I try to use it:

```
let appContext = new D2L.ApplicationContext('asd', 'asd').createUrlForAuthentication('wlutest.brightspace.com', 443, 'localhost:8100/callback');
```

this error pops up:

> ERROR TypeError: _valenceES6__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.ApplicationContext is not a constructor

I have tried generating d.ts for this module but the only effect seems to be calming my IDE down but the error remains.
I have no prior experience with JavaScript but starting from line 193 of `valence.js` seems like a proper constructor to me:

```
/**
 * Build a new ApplicationContext instance.
 *
 * An application context stores the state of the application (app ID, and app
 * Key) and provides methods for authentication. Given the authentication
 * information, it creates a {@link D2L.UserContext} with the appropriate
 * arguments.
 *
 * @param {String} appId Application ID as provided by Desire2Learn's key tool.
 * @param {String} appKey Application Key as provided by Desire2Learn's key tool.
 *
 * @constructor
 * @this {D2L.ApplicationContext}
 */
D2L.ApplicationContext =
    function (appId, appKey) {
        // Previous version took an appUrl as a first argument but threw it
        // away. This provides backwards compatibility for that contract.
        if (arguments.length === 3) {
            appId = arguments[1];
            appKey = arguments[2];
        }

        this.appId = appId;
        this.appKey = appKey;
    };
```

I have also tried converting this file to other js versions using tools with no luck getting this to work. Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Try `let appContext = D2L.ApplicationContext('asd', 'asd')` without `new`

Comment: @Dimanoid when I remove the `new` I get `ERROR TypeError: _valenceES6__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.ApplicationContext is not a function` Which is normal and fine. since a class prototype should not be called directly. But the compilation passed so it knows that ApplicationContext exists.

Comment: Does your TS config have allowSyntheticDefaultImports enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the module I used is so out of date and it does not even have `module.exports = ...` at the end of the JS file. after adding that, my project can recognize the library now.